# Not getting expected results with null values using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to get `null` or a `0` value from a mysql query and the results I get are not what I'm looking for. I'm sure I'm not even going about it with the right query.

Here's an sqlfiddle that shows the data I'm working with.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7c5198/1

I need returned all of the `Product_ID` numbers with the corresponding values. As the `value` or `null`.
Here's my query...

```
SELECT
`apl`.`Product_ID` PID,
`apl`.`Carries` Crs,
`apl`.`Approved` APV,
`o`.`Customer_ID` CID,
`oln`.`ProductName`,
`oln`.`Product_ID` PID ,
`Distributor_Name` DNAME,
sum(`oln`.`qty`) as tqty,
count(distinct(`o`.`Order_ID`)) as OdWith,
max(`o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime`) as LastOrder

FROM `Orders` `o`
JOIN `Customers` `c` ON `c`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`
JOIN `CustomerDetails` `cd` ON `cd`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`
JOIN `_Distributors` `d` ON `d`.`Distributor_ID` = `cd`.`Distributor_ID`

LEFT JOIN `Order_LineDetails` `oln` ON `oln`.`Order_ID` = `o`.`Order_ID`
  AND (
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "2872" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3032" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3043" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3419" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3613" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3614" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3671" OR
    `oln`.`Product_ID` = "3672" 
      )

LEFT JOIN `APL_LIST` `apl` ON `apl`.`Customer_ID` =  `o`.`Customer_ID` AND `apl`.`Product_ID` = `oln`.`Product_ID`

WHERE `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND `o`.`Customer_ID` = 6614
AND `oln`.`Product_ID` = `apl`.`Product_ID`
AND `o`.`IsVOID` = 0
GROUP BY `oln`.`Product_ID`
ORDER BY `oln`.`Product_ID`, `LastOrder`
```

Here's what I'm getting...

[image]

And this is what I would like to have returned...

[image]

The red is what I'm missing from the original query.

I'm trying to do this without using a loop in php. If anyone has any ideas please point me in the right direction!

### EDIT

Okay here's a new fiddle..
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0db52/2

I've tried to simplify my query based on the suggestions but I'm still missing the details I need. I may need to totally change my query to get what I want. But I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. If you see the second image, it has red lines. Those are the lines that I would like to return in my result. I'm hoping to get this right as a single mysql query instead of using a loop in php.

Comment: You are using left joined tables in your `WHERE` clause. That changes those `LEFT JOINS` to INNER ones. Place those conditions in the `ON` clause of the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: For readability, it may be easier to use an IN () for those Product_IDs.

Answer (score 0):

As VMai indicates above, the problem is that you have this bit in your `WHERE`-clause:

```
AND `oln`.`Product_ID` = `apl`.`Product_ID`
```

This condition can only be satisfied for records where the join to `apl` succeeded, so it makes the `LEFT JOIN` pointless.

To fix this, you can move that clause to be inside your `ON` clause instead. (Or, you can perhaps simply remove it; judging from the table-names and so on, I'm guessing that what you already have in the `ON` clause is enough?)

Comment: I moved it up, but I'm still not getting it right. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try your query like below, since in your last join you already mentioned the condition

```
`apl`.`Product_ID` = `oln`.`Product_ID
```

I have removed it from `WHERE` condition. See your updated fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7c5198/13

```
SELECT
`apl`.`Product_ID` PID,
`apl`.`Carries` Crs,
`apl`.`Approved` APV,
`o`.`Customer_ID` CID,
`oln`.`ProductName`,
`oln`.`Product_ID` PID ,
`Distributor_Name` DNAME,
sum(`oln`.`qty`) as tqty,
count(distinct(`o`.`Order_ID`)) as OdWith,
max(`o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime`) as LastOrder
FROM `Orders` `o`
LEFT JOIN `Customers` `c` 
ON `c`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`

LEFT JOIN `CustomerDetails` `cd` 
ON `cd`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`

LEFT JOIN `_Distributors` `d` 
ON `d`.`Distributor_ID` = `cd`.`Distributor_ID`

LEFT JOIN `Order_LineDetails` `oln` 
ON `oln`.`Order_ID` = `o`.`Order_ID`
  AND 
    `oln`.`Product_ID` in 
('2872','3032','3043','3419','3613','3614','3671','3672')

LEFT JOIN `APL_LIST` `apl` 
ON `apl`.`Customer_ID` =  `o`.`Customer_ID` 
AND `apl`.`Product_ID` = `oln`.`Product_ID`

WHERE `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` > 
DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND `o`.`Customer_ID` = '6614'
AND `o`.`IsVOID` = 0

GROUP BY `oln`.`Product_ID`
ORDER BY `oln`.`Product_ID`, `LastOrder`
```

Comment: I changed the fiddle to try to simplify it but it does not produce the results I'm going for.

Comment: @Monty, did you tried the query I have provided in my answer (or in fiddle link in my answer)? I think no ... try that with your actual data set and you will get desired result.

Comment: thanks for your help. I did try your solution and it works partially for what I need. I am still trying to figure out how to show each of the `Product_ID` as showing the number, and as `null`. Like in the second image.